# How to show that $1$ is an attracting period-2 point.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to solve this question, here is my solution, is it correct?

**Question**: Let $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+\frac{1}{2}$. Show that $1$ is an attracting period-2 point.

**Solution**:

$$f(1)=-1$$$$f(-1)=f(f(1))=1$$

Hence $x=1$ is a period-2 point. Since

$$f^\prime(x)=-x-1$$

then

$$|f^{\prime}(1)f^{\prime}(-1)|=|(-2)\times 0|=0<1$$

Hence $x=1$ is an attracting period-2 point.

Comment: Right, $|(f^2)'(1)|=|f^{\prime}(-1)\;f^{\prime}(1)|=0<1.$